# creating unprotected pdfs using mPDF

Tags: pdf, mpdf, protected

I use mPDF to create pdfs. Now I need to create pdf files unprotected. With SetProtection () I have everything enabled but the pdf is still SECURED. Can somewhere set up to make the pdf file completely unprotected?

Thank you for your help

Comment: We upload a PDF to another system to reject this file. By using the adobe acrobat I will turn off the protection, but it is tedious

Answer (score 2):

Simply do NOT call `SetProtection()` and you're done.

Comment: Hello,

thank you for the advice. It's functional. I did not notice that I had SetProtection () set in another part of the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try it to after wirteHTML(); and before output();

```
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), '123456', '123456');
```